# rails slim syntax error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slim-lang

hogehoge.html.erb

```
<% flash.each do |key, value| %>
<div class="alert alert-<%= key %>"><%= value %></div>
<% end %>
```

I want to transrate into

hogehoge.html.slim

can anybody help me?

Comment: I'm open to help you but I'm a little bit afraid that 'transrating' this file to me has no sense : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like below should do the work:

```
-flash.each do |key, value|
  div class="alert alert-#{key}"
    = value
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- flash.each do |key, value| 
  div class="alert alert-#{key}"
    = value
```